# Hello I'm very new to xml and c#, I'm basically trying to create a bot through xml and using xml text reader

Tags: c#, xml

If anybody could give me a few tips and an example in both XML and c# on how it actually works, I learn a lot better by playing about with the codes myself but actually creating them at the moment is driving me crazy. I just want to type hello and get a few responces like, hi, you okay, good day etc.. Any help will be much appreciated thanks in advance guys

Comment: You haven't really given us a real question hear that we can help you with - you need to be far more specific. You could easily write an application to give you your responses without using XML - how do you want to use XML to achieve what you want. Some examples showing what you want & what you have tried will get a better response. If you are just looking for help in learning XML &/or C# - then look for books, use Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't been very specific in your question but this is the only piece of C# XML code I have to hand:

```
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("");
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("", "");
xmlWriter.WriteValue(10);
xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
```

You may also want to look at the XML Serizalizer. Below is a code sample in regards to this:

```
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            serializer.Serialize(writer, myClass);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(writer.ToString());
                                            return sb.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new System.Exception("" + ex.Message);
        }
```